# How to redirect to this URL with dynamic source URL?

Tags: iis

I want to redirect all of the 404 traffic to root (this is already done) and add in an get parameter `?utm_source=sourceurl.com` where sourceurl.com would be the original URL the user visited.

How to accomplish this with the newest version of IIS?

**UPDATE**

I already have this in my web.config configured:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I need to combine this old rule with the new rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated rule:

```
<rule name="AngularJS Routes1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sample.com/index.html?test={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
```

[image]

below is failed request tracing result:

[image]

Comment: Where do I put this XML? Just into the input field?

Comment: @Munchkin you have to use the IIS URL rewrite rule extention.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Can't I just copy-paste into my Angular project's web.config instead? I'm pretty sure I already have the rewrite module installed

Comment: I updated the question to contain the already configured configuration.

Comment: If I add the rule afterwards it just throws me an 500 error whereever I try to go...

Comment: @Munchkin do you want to match the hostname or requested path? yes, you can modify web.cinfg directly. could you please share the error.

Comment: Problem is that the 500 errors don't show up in the logs... What can I do to make them show up?

Comment: The first configurtion I added in the question just rewrites to the root path, since it's an Angular app.

Comment: @Munchkin could you share  what is your exact requirement

Comment: I managed to your rule additionally but then the Angular App goes blank and the only error in the console is that the MIME-Types don't match. I tried manually overriding them but that did not fix the problem. My requirement is to combine the previous functionality (see the question) with the answer you provided

Comment: I will give you a bounty if you answer the question completely with the new problem that I've included (combining these two rules)

Comment: Bounty is up btw

Comment: @Munchkin please check the updated rule and result.

Comment: Thanks. One small question: How did you trace the redirect like that? What software did you use?

Comment: @Munchkin you can use iis failed request tracing feature. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis